# File Exchange migrate to Feed API without OAuth in eBay

Tags: ebay-api

How can I use bulk data exchange using only auth'n'auth token.
My application does not have the ability to use OAuth because it works without users in the cron job.
Any ideas or examples?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there's no solution since service has been dismissed.
You can try with some SaaS solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: SaaS as bulkuploader.eu

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RefreshToken which you can use for 18 months.
with this refresh token you can create your OAuth access Token und use the sell feed api